# Pivot table, multiple spreadsheets

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have multiple spreadsheets that all have different data. I tried multiple consolidation ranges but it didn't let me select the data I wanted.

I have 2 columns in each spreadsheet (many) with the same table title that I want to use (they are not in the same place in each sheet, and are only one of many columns - this cannot be changed). I still want to combine them without manually copying them as this takes too much time.

I have "Quality" and "Date". For "Quality" I have "Good" and "Bad". I want to be able to create a pivot where I can select "Quality: Good/Bad" as the  report filter, then show the dates in the first column below and a count on the right (so I can see if there has been any new "Bad" ones for example in the later dates, like "Ah, a new date has appeared, and there is two new bad ones).

Can this even be done? I have twisted and turned and not come up with anything but errors.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot tables will only take data form one source. 
If you're desperate to use Powerpivot, then your options are either to:

A: Create a "master" table that pulls all the data into one place

B: use [Powerpivot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413497%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), as it can use data from more than one source.

Difficulty here is of course learning a completely new program and syntax (dax is similar but very different to Excel's formulaic language)

If you go down the powerpivot route, I found [ExcelIsFun's tutorials on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/user/ExcelIsFun) incredibly useful.